# How do I use Assert with Selenium WebDriver to check if it logged in successfully?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using selenium so I am a little unsure what I should use in this case.

Here is what I think it is:

```
Assert.assertTrue("user should be logged in", driver.equals("username").startsWith("username"));
```

Please guide.

Comment: You can have a check on the title of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check page title to verify whether user has logged in successfully.
Once you click on login button and user gets landing page(page after user logins successfully), get the page title and check whether its expected title.

```
Assert.assertTrue("User logged in successfully? ", driver.getTitle().trim().equals("expected title");
```

Comment: is there a way to show each event as a different test

Comment: It does 7 events but when it's done it tell me MyFirstTest: 1 total, 1 passed

Comment: What events are you using? Events means actions/steps?..Give some examples.

Comment: It looks like this
@Test
    public void startWebDriver(){

        //Uses firefox
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Finds website
        driver.navigate().to("url");
        Assert.assertTrue("title should start with title", driver.getTitle().startsWith("title"));
        System.out.println("We are on the correct Web Page");

        //Maximizes the web browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: I just added a system.out.prinln(); to log out the result

Comment: See, each @ Test represents one test. So whatever you write in @ Test method is considered as one test. You need to add multiple @ Test methods with different events in it. This way it will consider each @ Test method a separate test.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. Do I have to have start a new WebDriver each time?

Comment: No, create single driver globally in class and use it in different methods of that class.

Comment: I tried using this and it didn't work

@Before 
public void setUp() {
        driver = new MyFirefoxDriver();
    }

Comment: Sorry it looks like this 

public class mainTest {
    private MyFirefoxDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new MyFirefoxDriver();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the message for a successful log out or some sort of parameter is present. So it could be something as simple as a line of text, or perhaps an element has been added/removed.